# VBA auto-groups rows with certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to group rows that has certain indention in certain cell. For example, I want to group row 12 and 13, row 14 and 15, row 15 to 27 in the screen shot below:
[image: screenshot]

And I tried to write a code and obviously it doesn't work, can somebody help fix it? 
Thanks!

```
Sub autogroup()

Dim c As Range
Dim rng0 As Range
Dim block As Range

Set block = Range("c12:c179")

For Each c In block
    If Not IsEmpty(c) And Left(c.Select, 10) = "          " Then
        If rng0 Is Nothing Then
            Set rng0 = c
        Else
            Set rng0 = Union(rng0, c)
        End If
    End If
    If Not Left(c.Select, 10) = "          " Then
        Set rng0 = Union(rng0, c)
    End If
Next c

For Each c In rng0.Areas
    c.EntireRow.Group
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work?

Comment: Start with `Left(c, 10)` without the Select. And then tell us what "doesn't work" means exactly.

Comment: also make sure the indentations are really there because of spaces entered in the cell. If they are formatting indents, this code will not work.

Comment: If you're trying to group rows, you're going to run into a major issue with the scenario you've described in the post.  `.Group` 12 & 13 will give them a subtotal button, and when you try to `.Group` 14 & 15 you will group up 12, 13, 14, & 15, together.  You need to have non-grouped rows between groupings so that they are separated.  Similarly, if you have major groupings (e.g., subtotal 1 and 2) you will need to be off-set by 1 row so that you don't have only one grouping.

Comment: Please show us the expected result.

Comment: Please take a look and [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200908/106798) and see if it helps.